# 404 Error in accessing https URL - Java , but working fine with POSTMAN or SOAPUI

Tags: java, post, token, api-key

**Edit on 21st Nov :** I have tried in accessing the URL directly using browser, it gives me the same 404 error response. But while checking in POSTMAN - code , i could see the call goes as below. So can someone please let me know how to send the call in sameway? thanks

POST /api/test/PW/authentication/user
 HTTP/1.1

Host: www.hostname.com
X-API-Key: saksj82kqjsak290d

cache-control: no-cache

Postman-Token: 2b7fl871-195a-4782-9000-6ce269242704

Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="credential"

user123

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

pass123
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--

**Original Message :** 
I have an issue while fetching token from a https Rest APi using Java code.
Request URL : **https://www.hostname.com/api/test/PW/authentication/user**
Curl : 
**curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'ApiKey: saksj82kqjsak290d -d 'userid=user123&password=pass123' 'https://www.hostname.com/api/test/PW/authentication/user'**
Method : POST

Once i send Post reqyest i will get the Token in Header values in JSON format. But while pinging the server i am getting 404 rsponse from Java. But with POSTMAN tool, i am getting the response as 200 with proper token in response header data.

Note : i have changed the URL here to some dummy.

So far i have tried as below and not sure where i have gone wrong.

```
                    import java.net.*;
                import java.io.*;
                import java.util.*;
                import java.io.BufferedReader;
                import java.io.DataOutputStream;
                import java.io.IOException;
                import java.io.InputStreamReader;
                import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
                import java.net.CookieHandler;
                import java.net.CookieManager;

                import java.net.URL;
                import java.net.URLEncoder;
                import java.util.ArrayList;
                import java.util.List;

                import java.util.Set;
                import java.net.HttpuConnection;

                import javax.net.ssl.HttpsuConnection;
                import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
                import java.net.MalformedURLException;

                public class Tokenhttps {
                    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

                        int code;

                        String httpsurl = "https://www.hostname.com/api/test/PW/authentication/user";

                        String KeytoPass = "saksj82kqjsak290d";

                        try{
                              URL httpurl = new URL(httpsurl);
                              HttpuConnection uConnect = (HttpuConnection) httpurl.openConnection();

                            //Set header
                              uConnect.setDoOutput(true);
                              uConnect.setRequestMethod("POST");
                              urlConnect.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                              uConnect.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                              uConnect.setRequestProperty("ApiKey", KeytoPass);

                            //Set body
                              String bodydata ="{\"userid\":\"user123\",\"password\":\"pass123\"}";

                            //POST
                            DataOutputStream  dos = new DataOutputStream (uConnect.getOutputStream ());
                            dos.write(bodydata.getBytes());
                            dos.flush();

                            // Read the response.
                            InputStreamReader isr = null;
                            code = uConnect.getResponseCode();
                          System.out.println("responseCode:" + code );
                            if (code == 200) {
                                System.out.println("Connection is Success" );
                               isr = new InputStreamReader(uConnect.getInputStream());
                             //Print Header Fields
                                  System.out.println("HeaderValues :"+uConnect.getHeaderFields ());
                                                } 
                           else {
                               isr = new InputStreamReader(uConnect.getErrorStream());
                            }
                        }

                         catch(Exception errormsg){
                          System.out.println("Error: " +errormsg);
                        }   
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Any inputs please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has worked with below change :

```
String bodaydata= "credential=user123&password=pass123";
```

Answer (score 2):

In the Java code, the bodydata is json but in the curl command you are passing in userid and password formatted as x-www-form-urlencoded. Most likely, the service is expecting the later so it isn't getting the proper values when you pass it in as the former.

Comment: I am sending  **x-www-form-urlencoded** in header only, just updated with the same. But User id and password i am sending in JSON format with curl braces. Still no luck. Can you please eloberate "Most likely, the service is expecting the later so it isn't getting the proper values when you pass it in as the former"

Comment: It looks like you already figured it out. When you set the content type to x-www-form-urlencoded, you are telling the server to expect the request data to be in a certain format. In this case, a format similar to how query strings get formatted. Originally, you sent the request data in a different format which was encoded as JSON. Because the server wasn't expecting that format, it didn't get the data you were sending correctly.

Comment: thanks for explantion, but actually after correcting the credentials in different format as specified below, the  content type to x-www-form-urlencoded is not really a required to send as I am already sending the to accept the format as application/json. However thank you very much for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `content-type` property in your java code. The server you're hitting might need that header to process the parameters you're passing with the POST request.

Comment: No luck, i have tried that as well, but same reponse code : 404. I am passing as per the CURL , but unable to get succeed with the same. But SOAP UI and POSTMan are working fine. Also not sure because of httpS url it requires some additionalcode as i am not sure of it.